# displaying distribution of categorical variable using ggplot and r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Simplifying my question in terms of generic titanic dataset:

how can i get a following plot for all the attributes in my dataset[image]

If possible, i would also want to get the count or percentage for each category.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Regards, Trupti

Comment: As soon as you get your data into a proper format, you should be able to use something [like this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Titanic data set this can be accomplished using

```
library(tidyverse)
data("Titanic")

Titanic %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%    # transform from a table to dataframe
  gather(variable, value, -Freq) %>%  # change to long format
  group_by(variable, value) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>% # get the freq for each level of each variable
  ggplot(aes(variable, Freq, fill = value)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value, " (", Freq, ")")), vjust = 1, 
            position = position_stack()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: That helps. Thank you :)